# Incorrect module loading order with TypeScript compiler option "module": "es2015"

Tags: typescript, webpack

We are using WebPack 3.10.0 with awesome-typescript-loader 3.4.1 (TS version is 2.6.2). Relevant snippet:

```
const win = <any>window;

...

console.log('jQuery before', {import: jQuery, win$: win.$, winJQuery: win.jQuery});

import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

win.jQuery = win.$ = jQuery;
console.log('jQuery after', {import: jQuery, win$: win.$, winJQuery: win.jQuery});

...

import 'bootstrap';
```

In the real code there is a few lines between loading jQuery and Bootstrap. Without these lines Bootstrap won't start (putting dummy tether and popper instances on a window object to not waste bandwidth since we are not using anything from Bootstrap which uses these libraries).

### "module": "commonjs"

Bootstrap starts alright, the log contains expected result:

```
jQuery before {import: undefined, win$: undefined, winJQuery: undefined}
jQuery after {import: ƒ, win$: ƒ, winJQuery: ƒ}
```

### "module": "es2015"

Bootstrap crashes with:

```
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
```

When Bootstrap import is removed, then following log is produced:

```
jQuery before {import: ƒ, win$: undefined, winJQuery: undefined}
jQuery after {import: ƒ, win$: ƒ, winJQuery: ƒ}
```

Notice that jQuery import is printed from the "future", because at the time of running "jQuery before" it should have not been imported yet.

### Question

I suspect the imports in es2015 are hoisted, which doesn't make much sense when one imports only for side-effects.

How to make imports respect order in which they are in code when using `"module": "es2015"`?

Or if this is not possible, is there any other way to defer loading of some module (e.g. Bootstrap) until code is executed, so I can set up proper environment the module is expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use require('') if you want to defer the loading of a module, this will not be hoisted

Comment: Using `require` is sadly not allowed when using es2015 module type :(.

Comment: What error do you see? I myself use require in some places, I use module es6, however I thought it'd be the same as es2015

Comment: Oh, you are right :D. `require('...')` is allowed, only `import ... = require('...')` is forbidden. Thank you!